# flutter clean and flutter run(ios) never end

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

`flutter clean -v` and `flutter run -v`(ios) get stuck at the same point.

```
[/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutterアプリ/battle3/ios/] 
xcrun xcodebuild -list
[  +23 ms] <- compile package:battle3/main.dart
```

At the above points they get stuck.

There is no problem with `flutter run` in chrome and android studio.

I attach the log below.

```
[   +7 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug
mode...
[  +10 ms]
/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
--disable-dart-dev
/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapsho
ts/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/com
mon/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill
/var/folders/8b/6r0l0j857wzgdxmz60t0xyk80000gn/T/flutter_tools.qBDa68/flutter_to
ol.xu1HmT/app.dill --packages
/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutterアプリ/battle3/.dart_tool/package
_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts
--track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root
--initialize-from-dill
build/c075001b96339384a97db4862b8ab8db.cache.dill.track.dill --source
/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutterアプリ/battle3/.dart_tool/flutter
_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source
package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart
-Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/developmen
t/flutter%E3%82%A2%E3%83%95%E3%82%9A%E3%83%AA/battle3/.dart_tool/flutter_build/d
art_plugin_registrant.dart --verbosity=error --flutter-widget-cache
--enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
[  +11 ms] executing:
[/Users/takeuchiraiaoi/Desktop/development/flutterアプリ/battle3/ios/] xcrun
xcodebuild -list
[  +23 ms] <- compile package:battle3/main.dart
^CtakeuchiraiaoinoMacBook-Air:ios takeuchiraiaoi$
```

Comment: Did you tried checking the disk for corruption?

Comment: Yes, I checked with Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0):

```
time xcrun xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -quiet clean
```

this works!

I think the simulator cache was probably the problem.

By this link.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56156#issuecomment-624287368